# How to measure First Screen Paint?

Tags: javascript, performance, dom, web-performance, core-web-vitals

Web Vitals comes with two well known metrics: FCP and LCP. It is good ideas to measure paint time. But I have different problem.

I have to implement a metric which describes when the *first screen completely loaded within viewport*. It means that I need to measure the least timing when:

> either body height larger than viewport height, or document completed

My first attempt to implement this was following:

Sets an interval which checks this condition every 200ms. Pseudo code:

```js
setInterval(() => {
  if (document.body.clientHeight > window.innerHeight || document.readyState === 'complete') {
    resolve(); // commit!
  }
}, 200);
```

But this way has two major issues:

1. it's inaccurate due to 200ms window;
2. it's inaccurate due to `setInterval` does not promise to perform a callback at the specified time.

The second way is to use `MutationObserver`. Pseudo code:

```js
new MutationObserver(() => {
  if (document.body.clientHeight > window.innerHeight || document.readyState === 'complete') {
    resolve(); // commit!
  }
}).observe(document.body, {attributes: false, childList: true, subtree: true});
```

It's fine and solves that issues, but there is a huge problem. In this way need to recalculate window height on each HTML commit. There is a problem for pages with large amount of HTML-chunks which comes from the server.

And this solutions become *irrelevant* to measure the first screen paint when resources for the first paints and first scripts execution are very important.

My question is **how to measure the First Screen Paint metric with minimal performance costs and sufficient accuracy?**

Maybe there is an API which I just don't know about :)

Comment: Or maybe there is an static property in browser API which checks browser displaying a scrollbar? :)

Comment: I mean "efficient" property to not to force a browser to do Layout Recalcution.

Comment: I don’t understand what the ask is here. Are you asking for the First Paint time (there’s an API for that) or the last paint time of the above the fold content (when everything is painted)?

Comment: I ask about time when the content in viewport is ready, one first screen

Comment: I mean neither first-paint, nor dcl, but the stage between when only first screen is ready. Usually it’s header and main content: first most relevant  search results or product card price and picture.

Answer (score 1):

The only metric to measure the "first screen" is [Speed Index](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/lighthouse/performance/speed-index), but it's a complex, resource-intensive, complex metric to calculate outside of the lab and is not recommended to measure in the field.

Other than that websites don't really work on screenfuls ("there is no fold"), nor are they static as new content is often continually loaded throughout (think social media feeds update, ads loading, notifications going off) so there is not real measure on when the page has stopped updating. Additionally, if the "first page" is fully rendered and then a small notification icon changes, or an ad plays, or a carousel automatically moves then when should this be measured.

I also don't understand why you think measuring client height/width is a good measure of this. Just because some content beneath the screen exists doesn't mean the content above the screen is complete.

This is why metrics have instead moved from First Paint (FP - which measures any paints), First Contentful Paint (FCP - which excludes non-contentful paints like just background colours), and Largest Contentful Paint (LCP - which tries to be a measure of what is the largest, and so presumably the most important, content).

If you want to measure when specific content is rendered, then [Element Timing](https://www.speedcurve.com/blog/element-timing-one-true-metric/) (which is what LCP is based on) is a good API to look at. The difference with FCP and LCP being that you, as a page owner, can decide which element to measure.

Comment: Products are built to show the most important content on the first screen. By the fact, LCP is very unstable RUM metric to follow, targeting large advert, but not really important specific content. Element Timing is bad for large applications with many different pages, it is custom and really hard to track thing. Measuring First Screen is not bad idea, especially for search results with a vast kind of content, which rendered sequentially by streaming server side.

Comment: Maybe, the fault of Speed Index was in complexity of being reproducible?

Comment: Is Speed Index more stable way to track visual stability than LCP? I mean not to debug, but to monitor RUM for a long time and understand.

Comment: Speed Index basically takes screenshots and tries to compare them to see how much change has happened. That's very expensive to do in RUM. And still would be susceptible to different ads coming in. To not use screenshots but use DOM APIs instead (like LCP, like Element Timing) yes has issues you've stated, but without the cost of Speed Index. There is no known way, for getting what you want is a resource-effective, stable way.