# Why long frame intervals do not the same as long tasks?

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, requestanimationframe, web-performance

In browser API, we can measure the distance between two frames by calling `requestAnimationFrame` recursively. If we start to collect all `requestAnimationFrame` calls while the page is loading, we can mention that sometimes on slow web pages, the distance between frames is more than `50ms + Frame Rate`.

`50ms` is a minimal interval for [long task](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceLongTaskTiming#description).

Then we can compare real Chrome long tasks (by observing `PerformanceLongTaskEntries`) with durations between recursive executions of `requestAnimationFrame` and find out that they are different.

There is a script to compare:

```html
<script>
const performanceApiLongTasks = [];
const recursiveRAFIntervals = [];

function recursiveRAF(callback) {
  let abort = false;

  let fn;
  fn = () => {
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      if (!abort) {
        callback();
        requestAnimationFrame(fn);
      }
    });
  }
  fn();

  return () => { abort = true; };
}

let prevFrameTime = performance.now();
const stopRaf = recursiveRAF(() => {
  const startTime = performance.now(); 

  recursiveRAFIntervals.push({
    startTime,
    duration: startTime - prevFrameTime,
  });

  prevFrameTime = startTime;
});

const observer = new PerformanceObserver(list => {
  list.getEntriesByType('longtask').forEach(entry => {
    performanceApiLongTasks.push(entry);
  });
});
observer.observe({type: 'longtask', buffered: true});

setTimeout(() => {
  stopRaf();
  observer.disconnect();

  compare();
}, 10_000);

function compare() {
  const frameRate = Math.min(...recursiveRAFIntervals.map(({duration}) => duration));
  console.log({
    performanceApiLongTasks,
    recursiveRAFIntervals,
    rafIntervals: recursiveRAFIntervals.filter(({duration}) => duration > 50 + frameRate),
    frameRate,
  });
}
</script>
```

Here, on the StackOverflow web page, I run this script on page load:

[image]

The duration and entry count of the two methods are different. My question is **why a long interval between two frames does not produce a long task?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rAF interval may be made up of lots of short tasks rather than one long task.

Long tasks also do not include the rendering phase (including the rAF callbacks themselves).

The [Long Animation Frames API (LoAF)](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/web-platform/long-animation-frames) has been specifically designed to address [these shortcomings](https://github.com/w3c/longtasks/blob/main/loaf-explainer.md#where-long-tasks-fall-short).

I’d be interested to see the results if you repeating your tests with that API. You’ll need to enable **experimental web platform features** in `chrome://flags` to enable that before it becomes enabled by default (currently scheduled for Chrome 123).

Comment: Thank you very much! I did not know about that API, this is very helpful. 

There is very interesting idea in readme to rid of 50ms, so I think it’s great take in that problem. 

Maybe you can help me with these problems: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77854499/how-to-measure-first-screen-paint and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77856743/tbt-but-for-the-whole-life-of-the-page, it’s also about performance. Thanks!